# KDB generating ERROR:file/path/location/sym os reports: No such file or directory

Tags: kdb

I am trying to save table as partition using `` .Q.dpt[hdbroot;.z.d;`tablename] ``.

But it's generating No such file or directory error, but the directory is present.

can you please help me on this.

I have created blank folder to store the data but it's checking for sym file while storing data.

I have created one blank folder and gave that folder path to `hdbroot` variable, but it's not working.

Comment: Could you provide the exact error output for us? There is not much information to go on here. .Q.dpt calls .Q.en which will create the sym file it it's not present, so it's not correct to say that kdb is checking and failing to find the sym file. Does the output in the error and the hdbroot variable exactly match what you expect? You can use `key` to determine whether a directory exists or not from kdb. What does `key hdbroot` return? An empty folder returns an empty symbol vector; a non-existent folder returns an empty general list. https://code.kx.com/q/ref/key/#whether-a-folder-exists

Answer (score 2):

I could replicate your error by trying to save to a location that doesn't exist on the machine.

```
q).Q.dpt[`:/does/not/exist;.z.d;`t]
'/does/not/exist/sym. OS reports: No such file or directory
  [0]  .Q.dpt[`:/does/not/exist;.z.d;`t]
```

Like I mentioned in my comment, make sure that the hdbroot variable is exactly the location you're expecting. `key` can help you determine this, here is a quick helper function for you.

```
q)exists:{"Folder/file ",$[11=abs type key x;"exists";"does not exist"]}
q)exists`:/does/not/exist
"Folder/file does not exist"
q)exists`:/tmp
"Folder/file exists"
```